# Can't Change Apache Jena Logging Level (using log4J2)

Tags: log4j, log4j2, slf4j, jena

I have included the **Apache Jena** library to my Java project and I am using **Apache Log4J2** as my logger. I have also included the **log4j-1.2-api** and **log4j-slf4j-impl** dependencies for mapping from **Log4J v1.x** and **SLF4J** (respectively).


However, I am unable to change the logging level for **Jena**!


I have tried setting it in the **log4j2.xml** (what I am using for my project):

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jena" level="warn"/>
```

And I have even tried adding a **log4j.properties** file:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.jena=WARN
```

With no success.


Has anyone else been able to solve this or a similar issue?

Comment: Your xml config snippet looks correct. Can you be more specific about “no success“? What is actually happening and what did you expect to happen? Note that you can troubleshoot the Log4j2 configuration by setting the `log4j2.debug` system property. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting

Comment: What is happening is that I still see Jena logs at their default levels (a lot of INFOs) and using their default layout. (I could try setting the `log4j2.debug` property, but I don't think **Log4J2** is actually handling up those logs.)

Comment: Try two things: set system property `log4j2.debug`, this will print Log4j2 initialization to the console. Also print the value of system property `java.class.path` to verify you aren’t accidentally using an old Log4j 1.2 on the classpath.

Comment: Which classes are you seeing output at level INFO? Apache Jena, the library, does not default to Log4j (or anything else) and rarely at INFO anyway.. The commands use log4j-1 for their output at INFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's help. I finally found the problem.

One of the other libraries, I am using, was importing **ch.qos.logback**, **logback-classic**.

I have excluded this import (in favor of **log4j-slf4j-impl**). And everything is working! :)